# Proving equivalence of two substitutions by induction

Tags: logic, proof-techniques, lambda-calculus, semantics, term-rewriting

I'm trying to prove the following reduction:
$$
     t\{x:=u\}\{y:=v\} = t\{y:=v\}\{x:=u\{y:=v\}\}
$$
under the following assumptions:

1. $x \neq y$
2. $x$ is not a free variable of $v$ (in symbols, $x \notin \operatorname{fv}(v)$).

My idea is to do it by induction, but I'm a bit stuck with the base case. I would appreciate if someone can explain to me how to write such a proof. I'm including what I tried, which is wrong or incomplete.

*Base case*: $t = m$ is just a variable.

On the left side we have:

```
if m = x ⟹ u{y:=v} (if u=y then v else u)
else     ⟹ m{y:=v} (if m=y then v else m)
```

On the right side we have:

```
if m=y ⟹ v{x:=u{y:=v}} (if u=y then v{x:=v} else u{x:=u}
  so we get either (v=x ⟹ v else v) or (u=x ⟹ u else u) 
else   ⟹ m{x:=u{y:=v}} (if m=y then m{x:=v} else m{x:=u}
  so we get either v or m
```

I understand we end up getting the same four branches, but is that considered really a proof? Is this the proper way to write such a proof and conclude the base case? Also, the given assumptions didn't help much here, so I think I'm missing the part where I need to use those assumptions...

I think once the base case is proven, we can do the following:

*Case $t = t_1t_2$:*

$$t\{x:=u\}\{y:=v\} \Longrightarrow t_1t_2\{x:=u\}\{y:=v\}
\Longrightarrow \\ t_1\{x:=u\}\{y:=v\} t_2\{x:=u\}\{y:=v\},$$
and we have just proven in the base case that
$t_1\{x:=u\}\{y:=v\} = t_1\{y:=v\}\{x:=u\{y:=v\}\}$  and  $t_2\{x:=u\}\{y:=v\} = t_2\{y:=v\}\{x:=u\{y:=v\}\}$,
so
\begin{align}
&t_1\{x:=u\}\{y:=v\} t_2\{x:=u\}\{y:=v\} \\ =& t_1\{y:=v\}\{x:=u\{y:=v\}\} t_2\{y:=v\}\{x:=u\{y:=v\}\} \\
= &t_1t_2\{x:=u\}\{y:=v\} \\ = &t_1t_2\{y:=v\}\{x:=u\{y:=v\}\}.
\end{align}

Now only case left is $t= \lambda m . t$.
So we have $(\lambda m . t)\{x:=u\}\{y:=v\}$,
which can be directly re-written as $\lambda m . t\{x:=u\}\{y:=v\}$, which is the base case again...

Could someone please help me finish this proof correctly and explain to me the right way to do it?

Comment: Your text is impossible to read. This is not how one would write a proof. I started rewriting your proof, but since your question is about how to write proofs, I abandoned my attempt. Consult some lecture notes to see how proofs are usually written.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thx for taking the time to rewrite my question and answer me with such clear explanation !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let us show that the two assumptions are necessary. Here is an example showing what goes wrong when $x = y$. Take $t = x$, $u = 1$, $v = 2$. We have
$$
x\{x := 1\}\{x := 2\} = 1\{x := 2\} = 1,
$$
whereas
$$
x\{x := 2\}\{x := 1\{x := 2\}\} =
2\{x := 1\} = 2.
$$

Next, here is an example showing what goes wrong when $x$ is not free in $v$. Take $t = y$, $x = 1$, $y = x$. We have
$$
y \{x := 1\}\{y := x\} = y\{y := x\} = x,
$$
whereas
$$
y \{y := x\}\{x := 1\{y := x\}\} =
x\{x := 1\} = 1.
$$

Now let's do the base case more carefully. The term $t$ is just a variable. We have to consider three possibilities: $t=x$, $t=y$, $t \neq x,y$.

If $t=x$ then $t\{x := u\} = u$, and so the left-hand side is $u\{y := v\} = u\{y := v\}$. On the other hand, $t\{y := v\} = x$ (since $x \neq y$), and so the right-hand side is $x\{x := u\{y := v\}\} = u \{y := v\}$.

If $t=y$ then $t\{x := u\} = y$ (since $y \neq x$), and so the left-hand side is $y\{y := v\} = v$. On the other hand, $t\{y := v\} = v$, and so the right-hand side is $v\{ x:= u\{y := v\} \} = v$, since $x$ doesn't appear freely in $v$.

Finally, if $t \neq x,y$ then both sides are just equal to $t$, since the substitutions have no effect.

Next, the rest of the proof. The proof for function application is essentially as you wrote it. Let us denote the left-hand side by $L(t)$ and the right-hand side by $R(t)$. If $t = t_1t_2$ then
$$
L(t) = L(t_1) L(t_2) \stackrel{(\ast)}= R(t_1) R(t_2) = R(t),
$$
where $(\ast)$ is due to the induction hypothesis.

Finally, we need to handle abstraction. Let $t = \lambda m.s$. Applying $\alpha$-conversion, we can assume without loss of generality that $m \neq x,y$. This implies that
$$
L(t) = \lambda m.L(s) = \lambda m.R(s) = R(t).
$$
To see why $\alpha$-conversion is necessary, try doing the proof when $m=x$ or $m=y$. The case $m=x$ works out fine, but you will encounter a problem when $m=y$.